# Отслеживание работы с консолью дочернего процесса

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Я использую Python 3.6, библиотеку multiprocessing.

Есть функция processing(), которая что-то пишет в консоль. Эта функция запускается из main() следующим образом:

`p = multiprocessing.Process(target=processing)`

Это долго выполняющаяся функция.

При этом main() в цикле ждёт ввода от пользователя.

```
while True:
   print("input command: ")
   inp = input()
   if inp == "processing":
      p = multiprocessing.Process(target=processing)
      p.start()
   if inp == "whatever":
      whatever()
```

Получается ситуация, когда main() дал приглашение и ждёт ввода, а processing пишет после этого.

```
input command:
*processing*
input command:           <-приглашение есть, но дальше выводится текст
processing started
processing finished
```

**Вопрос в том**, можно ли из main() как-то отслеживать запись в консоль *стороннего* текста и повторять приглашение?

Comment: Как понять "сторонний текст" ?

Comment: @KryTer_NexT текст, выведенный не текущий процессом, что ли. ну вот как в примере - "processing started" и "processing finished" выведены не тем же процессом, в котором исполняется main(), а процессом, в котором исполняется processing()

Comment: Ну это логично немного, и как я понял по вашему коду, при ввода слова Processing вы сразу же запускаете процесс.. А тот делает свои дела там параллельно.. И выводит то что ему сказанно.. И как я понял вы хотите сделать так чтобы он ожидал? Или выводил весь текст после кода main?

Comment: @KryTer_NexT и я не спорю, что это логично. но прочитайте вопрос ещё раз - я спрашиваю, можно ли мейна как-то отслеживать факт записи в консоль

Comment: Да да я понял :) Вот так просто взять отследить будет трудно, но есть хорошая библиотека для этого [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/index.html), если вы разберетесь с ней думаю это будет очень хорошо.. Данная библиотека созданна чтобы следить за дочерними процессами

Comment: Я делал класс-обертку для `Pipe`, чтобы она притворялась устройством stdout (достаточно реализовать методы `write` и `flush`), а дальше в дочернем процессе подменял `sys.stdout` на этот объект.